# show all open browser windows in firefox

Tags: firefox

If i have fire fox open, then open a new window, from a link or from the file menu,i have to drag the first window out of the way to get to the other. is there a way to show the other open windows?
this is also a pain with pop-ups, as i could have 20 windows open.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I don't understand the question. "**If i have fire fox open, then open a new window, from a link or from the file menu**". So the new window is a Firefox window? Like, when you click a link, it opens another Firefox window? "**i have to drag the first window out of the way to get to the other**". This means that the second window opens up in the background, right, behind the first, original window? "**is there a way to show the other open windows?**". Now what does this mean? What other open windows? Firefox windows? Or all other windows in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of open a new window, choose open in a new Tab.  That way you can have those tabs open in the same windows, and you can switch between them by just clicking on the desired Tab.

[image]

[image]

And yes you can have as may tabs open a you like.

[image]

Comment: You can also use the middle click to directly open new tabs. Same operation, middleclicking but on the tab, to close them.

Answer (score 2):

I didn’t get your question either, but you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (the key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>) to switch between windows of the same app.